# How to change selection popup for countries in sap

Tags: selection, popupwindow, sap-basis, sap-data-dictionary

I want to change the SAP selection table that can be popped up when entering a country - I think it is table `T005T` (countries).

Could you please tell me how to change the entries?

Or show a completely different table with different entries, or disable the selection pop up?

Comment: Does the table you use have a reference to a domain (via a data element) with check table T005t?

Comment: Could you please provide the technical name of the target field? There are various country fields throughout the system.

Comment: thanks, guys, i found the answer in tx se11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description of your problem is missing some detailed information, but I try a guess:

You have a self defined table and you miss the F4-Help.

In SE11 you define your field. There you can also define the foreign key:

[image]

With this definition you get also a F4-help in selection screens.